# WinHttpQueryDataAvailable says there's less data available than expected

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

When using [WinHttpQueryDataAvailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpquerydataavailable) I noticed that it's returning less bytes than are actually available.

Here's my code:

```
// retrieve the response
if (WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL) == 0) { // response of 0 means we failed
    DWORD lastErr = GetLastError();
    return (int)lastErr;
}

// Query the server for available data
DWORD dwSize = 0;
if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize)) {
    DWORD lastErr = GetLastError();
    return (int)lastErr;
}

// Read the data from the server
DWORD bufferLen = 0;
DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, data + bufferLen, dwSize, &dwDownloaded)) {
    DWORD lastErr = GetLastError();
    return (int)lastErr;
}
```

`dwSize` is set to 3687 after calling `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize)`, but the server actually has 3986 bytes available. This causes my `WinHttpReadData` to return an incomplete message.

So my question is, why is it returning 3687 instead of 3986? Is this a packet issue? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpquerydataavailable) doesn't seem to mention needing to call this code multiple times to build the response from what I can see.

Comment: "*The documentation doesn't seem to mention needing to call this code multiple times*" - actually, it does, in a round-about way: "*This function returns the number of bytes of data that are **available to read immediately** by a subsequent call to WinHttpReadData...The amount of data that remains **is not recalculated until all available data indicated by the call to WinHttpQueryDataAvailable is read**. Use the return value of WinHttpReadData to determine when a response has been completely read.*".

Comment: Even the code example given in the doc shows `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable()` and `WinHttpReadData()` being called in a loop until the `dwSize` available to read falls to 0.  You need to do the same in your code.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help! I totally missed the do-while loop.